# Is there any shorthand to sum all the values of a ROW if the column names are consecutive years?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
id   1927  1928  1929  1930  1931  ...  2017  2018
1    int   int   int   int   int   ...  int   int
2    int   int   int   int   int   ...  int   int
3    int   int   int   int   int   ...  int   int
4    int   int   int   int   int   ...  int   int
... 
785  int   int   int   int   int   ...  int   int
786  int   int   int   int   int   ...  int   int
```

I want to find all rows that have a sum of over 50000 between 1945-1990.

Is there any shorthand available other than SELECT * WHERE `1945`+`1946` + ... + `1990` > 50000?

Comment: You may think of stored procedure / PLSQL to achieve this kind of requirement. Inside SP you can iterate over and do sum of columns in the way you need.

Comment: @Brien yes it's a real table. I'm making an app to analyze the first names used by people in the US. I already populated my table. Raw data comes from https://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/limits.html

Comment: See normalisation and fix your schema accordingly. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Comment: Hi @Strawberry, my table is level 123 normalized

Comment: There's a sense in which that's true - but it requires an interpretation of 1NF with which I don't agree. A more typical (and practical) design might look as follows:`id  year val`

Answer (score -2):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but maybe something like this:

```
select id, sum(year) as sum_year from table
where sum_year > 1000
group by id;
```

*Make sure to include a better example if you need help in the future. Your question is not clear.

Comment: It was a bad question, Brien. Stop it with the overpowered zeal, whoever you are.

Comment: I answered in hope he would provide more specifics. Unanswered questions are actually more discouraging than so-called wrong answers for new members. Also, what you're doing right now is what's ACTUALLY WRONG. Encourage activity - don't suppress it. This will be my last reply to you.

Comment: Hi @Joseph, thanks for you answer. There is no column called `year` in my table, so I can't do a sum(year). As the question title says, I want to sum the values in a row, not a column.

Comment: I look down the list, and tend to navigate more quickly to questions with 0 answers. So your assertion is misguided. Even if the data was stored correctly, this *still* wouldn't be an appropriate answer.